# The more "SQL-syntax" of Linq.Except

Tags: c#, linq, syntax

Most expressions in Linq can be written in two syntaxs.
Basically, the *Method-syntax* and the *SQL-like-syntax*.

For example:

**Method-syntax:**
`var results = MySet.Where(n => n.Status == State.ACTIVE);`

**SQL-like-syntax:**
`var results = from n in MySet where n.Status == State.ACTIVE select n;`

I'd like to use `.Except` in the SQL-like-syntax, but can only find examples online where it is used in the Method-syntax.

Example:

```
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,20).ToArray();
int[] primes = new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };

//var composites = from n in numbers select n except primes; // This does not work.
var composites = numbers.Except(primes);                     // This works
return composites;
```

**Questions**
Are there formal names for what I'm calling Method-syntax and SQL-like-syntax?
Is there a way to do the SQL-like-syntax on the `except` operation?

Comment: It looks like it is called 'Query Syntax.' Why are you wanting to use query syntax? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there formal names for what I'm calling Method-form and SQL-like
>   syntax?

Yes one is Method Syntax and the other *(SQL like)* is query syntax (query expression written in query sytnax).

[LINQ Query Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)

> Query expressions are written in a declarative query syntax
>   introduced in C# 3.0.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

For your other question:

> Is there a way to do the SQL-like-syntax on the except operation?

No. I haven't seen `Except` with query syntax.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

> Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ)
>   documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax.
>   However, the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the
>   .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled. These
>   method calls invoke the standard query operators, which have names
>   such as **Where, Select, GroupBy, Join, Max, and Average**. You can
>   call them directly by using method syntax instead of query syntax.

So it appears you can only use `Where, Select, GroupBy, Join, Max, and Average` with Query Syntax.

Comment: Max and Average cannot be used in query syntax in C#.  (They can in VB though, which is likely the source of that error).

Answer (score 5):

The only methods with LINQ syntax support in C# are:

```
Where      // where
Select     // select / let
SelectMany // from
Join       // join
GroupBy    // group by
GroupJoin  // join into
```

And not even all the overloads of those. For everything else, you're stuck calling the methods yourself.

The only way to perform your query using LINQ syntax is to swap `Except` for a `GroupJoin`:

```
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
int[] primes = new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };

var composites = from n in numbers
                 join p in primes on n equals p into grp
                 where !grp.Any()
                 select n;
```

This probably isn't worth it, though -- it will be somewhat less efficient and probably not immediately understandable to those who don't have a solid grasp of LINQ.

F# supports a much greater set of [query expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx). Wish they'd bring some of it over to C#.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a combination of query and method syntax.

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
var primes = new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };

var composites = from n in numbers
                 where !(primes.Contains(n))
                 select n;
```