# Check if keyword exists in table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of keywords entered in a textbox:

```
List<string> keywords = frsKeywords.Value.Trim().Split(',').ToList();
```

and am doing something on them:

```
if (keywords.Count > 0)
    {
       var getKeywordsForThisProduct =
           from gk
           in DataConnection.CPDBM.MetaKeywords
           where gk.ProductCode == globalProduct.Code
           select gk;



        foreach (var keyword in getKeywordsForThisProduct)
            if (!keywords.Contains(keyword.KeywordContent))
                DataConnection.CPDBM.MetaKeywords.Remove(keyword);

        foreach (string keyword in keywords)
            {
                //TODO: best way to check if keyword exists in table or not and insert into it if does not exists
            }
    }
```

I'm looking for the best way to check if any keyword exists in table (in KeywordContent column) or not.

Answer (score 0):

The way to check if there's any intersection between two sets is to use an intersection operator. In LINQ that would be [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.100).aspx).

But it looks like you want the difference of the two sets, so use [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)

Unfortunately, you can't use query syntax in c# with `Except()`. See [The more "SQL-syntax" of Linq.Except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379810/the-more-sql-syntax-of-linq-except)